# Symbian Windows Phone bluetooth communication

Tags: c#, qt, windows-phone-7, bluetooth, symbian

If wanted to communicate bluetooth messages between Symbian and Windows Phone using Qt and C# respectively,how would I go about it? What apis or classes would be able to communicate between the two platforms?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Windows Phone 7 does not provide us any public API to communicate by Bluetooth.

So, you can't write apps which work with Bluetooth devices.

Comment: Do you have any idea if Microsoft will do anything about it? Or of a possible workaround fr a multilayer game?

Comment: You should wait till 29.10.2012 and MSFT will publish Windows Phone 8 (with SDK, I hope). They might change something with Bluetooth. What about the second question - you can communicate via the Internet connection. Just build a WebServer for your game.

Comment: I hought so but I need something for my existing 7.5 device.